# Can I use Sun's OpenSSO Apache WebAgent to integrate to a CA SiteMinder Policy Server?

Tags: security, apache, single-sign-on, saml, opensso

The official Web Agents user documentation does not state what version of SAML is supported.  I am trying to integrate this with a Policy Server that is not running Sun's OpenSSO policy server, so my only requirement is to support SAML 2.0.  Has anyone had experience with this type of setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, no, you can't use an agent from one with a policy server from the other. The Agent <--> Policy Server protocol is not a standard protocol.

However, if you are looking to set up federation between a SiteMinder instance and an Open SSO instance you might have more luck. [Here](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-4729/ggpgd?a=view) is an article from Sun describing one scenario for setting it up.

Open SSO supports both SAML 2.0 and SAML 1.1 if this helps.